# Possible to destroy a running game and then rerun it or run a different game

Tags: playn

I noticed that the PlayN doc says that you can only call `Playn.run` once.  Here is my scenario and I'm looking for advice on how to tackle it.

Let's say I have a list of games to choose from in a menu on my web page. Upon clicking a game, I call `PlayN.run` on that game and it runs on my web page inside the playn-root `div`.  Now lets say I want the user to be able to stop and load a new game by selecting a different one in the game list and load that into the `div` and play that.

How would I go about tackling that? Do I need to re-register the `HtmlPlatform` all over again and the play the new game?  Or is there a way to destroy the current game and then play the new game using the existing platform which is already registered in PlayN?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest route would be to just use normal HTML links and have each PlayN game be on its own web page (which could be in an iframe if you don't want the URL to change at the top of the browser).

Trying to clear out and reinitialize everything internally is just a big waste of effort when the web browser will take care of all of that for you when you reload the web page.